# Java Monitoring tool

Tags: java, email, notifications, monitor

I'm working for a company which developes an java based application that may be installed on windows or linux servers (depending on our client's wishes). As the servers running the application are located inside our customer's network we have to access the server via different VPN accesses.

So now we have different servers with different accesses - but I need a java monitoring tool which notifies our IT in case of any java based problems (memory problems, running out of space on the HDD, etc.). As of security reasons it may not be possible to use Nagios as the firewall may not be opened for it so I thought about a notification via E-Mail. I'd like to have a webapp (so it is useable for Windows and Linux) which monitors multiple values (must be configurable) and sends the mail if necessary.

I also asked Google but most of the monitoring tools have to be installed or need root access (on Linux systems) which we don't have in 99%.

Are there any other tools you can recommend?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: How is this a programming question? Please see the FAQ on what questions to ask here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have many options to choose java monitoring tools; See below;

- [jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html)
- [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/index.html)
- [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)
- [GCViewer](http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html)
- [PerfAnal](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/perfanal/)

and also uses commercial tools [apperfect](http://www.appperfect.com/) or [manageengine](http://www.manageengine.com/).

Comment: nice ideas so far - thanks!!

unfortunately most of the tools either have to be installed (such as aspectj which also needs X11 which we often don't have access to) or can be run as a GUI for existing files like heap dumps etc.

what I'd need would be an app which runs as a "background" webapp and always monitors the applications (could also happen via jmx as we're always using the same port for our application) and alarms me and my colleagues once an error occured or, e.g. permgen stays at 95% for at least x minutes...

still trying rhq - maybe that's what I'm looking for ;-)

Comment: Can visualvm have automiatic email notifications incase of any issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Try RHQ http://www.jboss.org/rhq. It is an open source monitoring & management platform. It is quite difficult to set up the environment, but once you have done it, you will get a vast amount of functionality. 
You can set up general alerts which can notify you via email, twitter, jabber, sms, etc.

Comment: it's a cool tool thanks for the hint but unfortunately it's not usable for our needs as it's to difficult to install on our customer's servers....

Comment: It's true that the agent-based systems are hard to set up, but you'll get more functionality then.

Answer (score 0):

[JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) is a good tool you can use. Also You can have look at [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). Actually I am using Spring framework and I use AOP to track exceptions like If I get an exception then it's log is emailed to the developer, you can use AspectJ for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the eginnovations Java monitoring tool - will do what you are looking for.

http://www.eginnovations.com/web/java-monitoring.htm